# Asp.net Progress Bar

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a project in which i post the deals regarding the clothing product. In the deal i set the buing limit of the product such i have shirt it price is $5 but if get 1oo item sale within the specified time i will sell the shirt in $4. In this senario need to use progress bar to show the status of deal such many items are booked for sale. Can any body tell is there a control in asp.net which i can use?

Comment: i'm afraid your question needs more specific programming information...

Answer (score 1):

There are some links:

http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/EOWeb/ProgressBar.aspx

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/05/aspnet_ajax_progress_bar_contr.html

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/progressbar.aspx